# javascript async function, caller not waiting. manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Do **NOT** delete my question. I have scoured the web, the documentations, I don't know why this is happening and deleting the question does **NOT** help. There no other similar questions to mine.

Here goes. Below is how I beleive it should happen. But even with all the async away promis syntax I place there, it doesn't happen. When the async function is called, no one waits for it to finish. Idk what else to do except daisychain everything under the async function which I am trying to avoid. Help please.

I have tried using `tabs= await getcurrenttab()`, but that causes an error saying it only works on async functions. Which the listener is not.

[image]

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "DHL Helper",
  "description": "This helper helps DHL's quality of life, improves mental health.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
  "matches":["*://servicenow.*.com/*",
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content_helper.js"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://www.blogger.com/",
    "*://*/*"
  ]
}
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log('got tabs id');
    tab = getCurrentTab();
    console.log('Active tab ' + tab.id);
});    
async function getCurrentTab(){
    console.log('trying to get tabs id');
    let queryOptions = {active: true, currentWindow: true};
    return await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions)
    .then((tabs) => {
        console.log('Obtained tab ID');
        console.log(tabs);
        return tabs[0];
    })
    .catch((Error) => {
        console.log('it failed');
        console.error;
        return;
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you tried using getCurrentTab().then(...) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
    console.log('got tabs id');
    tab = await getCurrentTab();
    console.log('Active tab ' + tab.id);
});
```

Your approach was already correct, but if you want to use await in the function await, you also have to make the executing function asyncronous.

Comment: thanks. I decided to step back and use common sense and tried it just before you answered. This is my first time making my own extension for QoL purposes

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito Thanks too. There is a first time for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

user mentions attempting to use `=await getCurrentTab()` but encounters error that await is only for async functions...

adding `async` to event listener function fixed the problem

change this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
```

to this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
```